minimizing $| x x^T - A |^2$ for a covariance matrix $A$
For a given covariance matrix $A$ (so $A$ is symmetrical and positive semidefinite), I want to find a vector $x$ such that  $| x x^T - A |^2$ is minimized. Here $|M|^2$ just means the sum of squares of every element in $M$
Basically I want to find a vector $x$ such that $x x^T$ can approximate this $A$ as much as possible.
Intuitively, this looks like a PCA problem. $x$ might just be the first principal component. But can we rigorously prove that's the case? Or can we solve this problem somehow?

Do you mean $xx^T$? PCA is rank 1 approximation, which means $xy^T$. Your problem is more restrictive than rank 1 approximation.

@Kakashi yes, and why is it more restrictive?

start with $A$ 2 by 2, see what happens.

@CuriousMind All rank 1 matrices are of the form $xy^T$. Your problem asks for an approximation of the form $xx^T$.

Since $A$ is symmetric and positive semidefinite, you can obtain an SVD of $A$ that has $U=V$ by simply computing the eigenvalue decomposition $A=U\Lambda U^{T}$.
You can then apply the Eckart-Mirsky-Young theorem to get a best (in Frobenius norm) rank one approximation $A \approx xx^{T}$, where $x=\sqrt{\lambda_{1}} U_{1}$.
Note that the optimal solution may not be unique.  Consider, for example, what happens if $A=I$.
